# Вложенность меню работает не корректно как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Если нажать на меню открывается под меню, все ок, если нажать на любом месте страницы меню закроется, тоже все ок. Если нажать еще раз на меню что бы закрыть, закрываться не хочет, почему?

И ни как не могу сделать что бы нормально работали все вложенности. Работает только первая вложенность когда кликаю на нее остальные нет, там 4 вложенности есть максимум. Вот [codepen](http://codepen.io/freeman0204/pen/vLzXdj).

```
$('.dropmenu li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropmenu_sub li').slideToggle(100);

    $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
        var div = $(".dropmenu_sub li"); // тут указываем ID элемента
        if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
            && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
            div.hide(); // скрываем его
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: мне кажется, вы собрали куски кода из разных мест и вышла каша. вы обращаетесь к `$(".dropmenu_sub li")` - это и первый уровень меню и последующий, потому оно неадекватно открывает вложенности. кроме того, вы считываете в начале клик по меню, а потом снова его считываете - в итоге открытие и закрытие меню перебивают друг друга. надо разобраться в желаемом поведении и порядок навести

Comment: Да с разных мест взял. Вторая часть кода  $(document).mouseup(function (e){  как понял работает правильно. 
Подскажите как написать правильно ту часть (дальше я уже думаю разберусь) что отвечает за вложенности. Я то понял что там что то не то. Уже по разному менял селекторы.
Если просто пишу .dropmenu то исчезает все меню после клика. Это понятно. Поэтому я написал .dropmenu_sub li. Может тогда начиная с второй вложенности дать другие классы каждой вложенности? Или метод .find заменить на какой то другой?

Comment: Почему вы не делаете раскрытие меню по hover? Так удобнее и проще реализовывать

Comment: [Минимальный пример](http://codepen.io/higimo/pen/YwOapy) на hover

Answer (score 1):

мне кажется, вы собрали куски кода из разных мест и вышла каша. вы обращаетесь к `$(".dropmenu_sub li")` - это и первый уровень меню и последующий, потому оно неадекватно открывает вложенности. кроме того, вы считываете в начале клик по меню, а потом снова его считываете - в итоге открытие и закрытие меню перебивают друг друга. надо разобраться в желаемом поведении и порядок навести

Answer (score -1):

У вас при открывании другого меню первое автоматически не закрывается, просто поверх первого отображается второе. Для исправления этого, при клике на любое из меню следует закрывать открытые, если такие имеются.